# Recharts: Position tooltip cursor over active point

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, recharts

I'm creating simple line chart with a tooltip. Is there a way to position my cursor over the active point instead of with an offset (photo below). [image]

Comment: Does this issue answer your question? https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/488

Comment: @keikai i don't want to change the tooltip position, i want the cursor (mouse) to not be offset with the tooltip cursor.

Comment: @guitard00d123 Watching this issue  . Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: the solution is to hide the tooltip and use the activeDot prop to pass a custom svg. then you can position it with the x y values that are provided.

Answer (score 0):

Great question, and the answer is definitely not straightforward in the ReCharts docs. X and Y coordinates of the active point are actually already passed as props to your custom tooltip component.

So if you log out props within your custom component, you'll get a wealth of information about - among other things - the data point in the visualization over which you are currently hovering.

```
const DottedTooltip = (props) => {
console.log(props);
...
```

You need to grab the required position information by destructuring it or accessing it from props and then using it to set something like the cx attribute with a `<circle>` svg or the d attribute of something like a `<path>`.

Here is an example of a dotted line cursor I implemented on a LineChart

```
const DottedTooltip = ({ points }) => {
  const xPos = points[0].x;

  return (
    <svg viewBox="0 0 509 156" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle cx={xPos} cy="1" r="1" fill="#919191" />
      <circle cx={xPos} cy="11" r="1" fill="#919191" />
      <circle cx={xPos} cy="21" r="1" fill="#919191" />
      <circle cx={xPos} cy="31" r="1" fill="#919191" />
      <circle cx={xPos} cy="41" r="1" fill="#919191" />
      <circle cx={xPos} cy="51" r="1" fill="#919191" />
      <circle cx={xPos} cy="61" r="1" fill="#919191" />
      <circle cx={xPos} cy="71" r="1" fill="#919191" />
      <circle cx={xPos} cy="81" r="1" fill="#919191" />
      <circle cx={xPos} cy="91" r="1" fill="#919191" />
      <circle cx={xPos} cy="101" r="1" fill="#919191" />
      <circle cx={xPos} cy="111" r="1" fill="#919191" />
      <circle cx={xPos} cy="121" r="1" fill="#919191" />
      <circle cx={xPos} cy="131" r="1" fill="#919191" />
      <circle cx={xPos} cy="141" r="1" fill="#919191" />
    </svg>
  );
};
```

FINAL NOTE: you are going to want to make sure to set the viewBox attribute of your custom svg equal to the dimensions of the whole graph to ensure the cursor will render across the whole visualization.